# How to Authorize/Authenticate an API request using an app id and app key

Tags: c#, http

I'm very new to APIs and I need a GET request to this api called WordTracker. WordTracker gives me an app id and an app key to authorize usage of their api. I've searched everywhere on how to authorize api request but none are working for me. I continue to get a 403 forbidden error. If anyone can help me or could just give me a template to authorize, I would really appreciate it. I'm using c# on a windows form application.

Comment: https://wordtracker.docs.apiary.io/#reference/authentication

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that you need to pass the app_id and app_key in the query string. Hence, you should try to append them to your GET-request, e.g.: http://url?app_key=xxx&app_id=yyy.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, thank you. Your answer was nice and to the point